# tesseractjs misbehaving on a series of same type images

Tags: javascript, node.js, tesseract.js

i have a series of images that are all the same size , same format and share the same color scheme and all of them have the same format of text. i want to use tesseractjs to return their text , but tesseract doesn't work the same on all of them. on some images it returns the text on some other it doesnt. this is my tesseract code:

```
import { createWorker } from "tesseract.js";

const worker = createWorker();

(async () => {
  await worker.load();
  await worker.loadLanguage("eng");
  await worker.initialize("eng");
  const {
    data: { text }
  } = await worker.recognize("image.png");
  console.log(text);
  await worker.terminate();
})();
```

code source : tesseract.js github

Answer (score 0):

it seems that images have a level of noise while they seem so clear and easy to read , some of them have higher level of noise which makes tesseract fail , so a preproccessing is needed in order to have a good result .